# Object Not Return From Promise Function

Tags: node.js, promise, yeoman

```
// Thing is a mongoose model imported from thing.model.js file (the mongoose in that file has been promisify)    
exports.show = function(req, res) {
   return res.json(getThing(req.params.id))
};

function getThing(thingID){
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID).then(function(thing){
     return thing;
  })
}
```

How Can I get the thing out of the function. Right now , it just returns an promise object (resolve and reject fields). If I remove the first 'return' in the getThing helper function, it will then returns nothing. (I tried console.log(thing in the then callback block and it works fine))

If I wrote in this way:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
              .then(function(thing){return res.json(thing);})
};
```

It will work! Why?

Comment: Thing is a mongoose model I defined in other file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your top snippet

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
   return res.json(getThing(req.params.id))
};

function getThing(thingID){
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID).then(function(thing){
     return thing;
  })
}
```

in `getThing` the .then is redundant, so `getThing` is essentially

```
function getThing(thingID){
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID);
}
```

so exports.show is basically

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
   return res.json(Thing.findByIdAsync(req.params.id))
};
```

you are essentially doing a res.json on a Promise

which is different to:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
    .then(function(thing){return res.json(thing);})
};
```

where you are returning a promise of res.json of the result of `findByIdAsync`

What you want to do if you want to split the functions

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
   return getThing(req.params.id)
    .then(function(thing){return res.json(thing);})
};

function getThing(thingID){
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID);
}
```

or

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
   return getThing(req.params.id);
};

function getThing(thingID){
  return Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID)
    .then(function(thing){return res.json(thing);});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is another scene: what if I want to return the value? (Forget about the exports.show = function(req, res) ) What if I want to directly return an object from getThing? (function getThing(thingID){
  Thing.findByIdAsync(thingID).then(function(thing){
    return thing;
  })
}) seems not working ?

Comment: You can't, because asynchronous code can't be made synchronous (though there may be ES7 that does, I'm not fully conversant with ES7)

Comment: What I am trying to ask is how to break the promise chain and get the object out as a function return (the res.json() is kinda special, since it will setoff to end-point as long as the code get executed, is that right? then what about the general using case)

Comment: what I'm telling you is that you can't. Promise chains are asynchronous (even with no asynchronous calls)

Comment: sry, forgot to delete that, that was a previous comment

Comment: @JaromandaX: Even ES7 doesn't break with this. `async` functions still return promises, they only have nicer syntax.

Comment: They "look" more synchronous I guess